# compare function for pairs not working

Tags: c++, vector, stl, std-pair

I have written my own compare function to sort a vector of pairs. My sort function should be like this.
The point (i,j) will be ahead of point(x,y) if it is closer to (5,5), vice-versa. I am finding the distance and then comparing based on that. 
      The code is

```
  #include<iostream>
  #include<stdlib.h>
  #include<cstdio>
  #include<vector>
  #include<algorithm>

  using namespace std;

  double distance(int a, int b,  int x, int y)
  {
     return sqrt(pow(a-x,2.0)+pow(b-y,2.0));
  }
  bool mycomp(const pair<int, int >&i, const pair<int, int >&j)
  {
    double dis=distance(i.first, i.second, 5,5);
    double dis2=distance(j.first, j.second, 5, 5);
    if(dis<dis2)
       return i.first< j.first;
    return i.first>j.first;
 }

 int main()
 {
    int n;
    cin>>n;
    vector<pair<int, int> > p;
    for(int i=0; i < n; i++)
    {
        int a,b;
        cin>>a >>b;
        p.push_back(make_pair(a,b));
    }
    sort(p.begin(),p.end(),mycomp);
    for(int i=0; i<n; i++)
        cout<<p[i].first<<" "<<p[i].second<<endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: If `a` is `(5,5)` and `b` is `(6,5)`, you'll have both `mycomp(a,b) == true` and `mycomp(b,a) == true`. This violates the conditions for `std::sort`.

Answer (score 0):

You did not specify what you mean by “not working,” so I’ll take that as license to point out anything I like about your code.

Your `mycomp` routine does not do what you describe. In particular, always make sure that a comparison routine is antisymmetric.

```
bool mycomp(const pair<int, int >&i, const pair<int, int >&j)
{
  double dis=distance(i.first, i.second, 5, 5);
  double dis2=distance(j.first, j.second, 5, 5);
  if (dis < dis2) {
    return true;
  }
  if (dis2 > dis) {
    return false;
  }
  // tie break
  return std::less<decltype(i)>(i,j);
}
```

If that line with the `decltype` does not work, you may have to spell the tie break out yourself.

Answer (score 0):

The answer by @ChristopherCreutzig should solve your problem. I'm going to suggest something that will obviate the need for computing a square root.

```
   int square(int a)
   {
      return a*a;
   }

   int distanceSquared(int a, int b,  int x, int y)
   {
      return square(a-x) + square(b-y);
   }

   bool mycomp(const pair<int, int >&i, const pair<int, int >&j)
   {
     double dis1 = distanceSquared(i.first, i.second, 5, 5);
     double dis2 = distanceSquared(j.first, j.second, 5, 5);
     if ( dis1 != dis2 )
        return (dis1 < dis2);

     return (i.first < j.first);
  }
```

Comment: Thanks that worked. can you tell how you thought for this
if ( dis1 != dis2 )
        return (dis1 < dis2);

Comment: dis1 and dis2 has nothing to do with the pairs. those are just temp values. How if dis1< dis2 the respective pair in the vector is ahead of the other . thanks

Comment: @user3126404, since you were using distance from (5, 5) as a way to sort the vector, I thought you could use that logic. You could as easily have used `if ( i.first != j.first ) return (i.first < j.first);`

Comment: why will this not work ?
  if ( dis1 == dis2 )
        return (i.first< j.first);
     else if (dis1 < dis2)
   return i.first < j.first;
  else 
   return j.first < i.first;

Comment: That's because it's not symmetric w.r.t. `i` and `j`.

Comment: Can you post your sample data and how you wish the sorted data to be?

Answer (score -1):

This is not the right condition check.
`if(dis<dis2)
return i.first< j.first
return i.first>j.first;`

Should suffice `return dis < dis2;`

Comment: This is not an answer. If you want to clarify something, add them as comments to the OP's question.

Comment: I don't want to clarify. I want to give a hint and an exercise for a beginner. No one will gain from a solution, with a hint one will.